# Nullpointerexception using entity manager

Tags: java, jboss, nullpointerexception, wildfly

I'm making a Maven project and deploying to a Wildfly 10 server using a UDP listener, I have my Facade connected to my DB (MariaDB).
I have a test webpage where I send an String to make the process, the problems come when I try to make the same process but with the UDP listener.

My UDP Server listens for the port and gets the message but using the same procedure I use in my webpage brings me the nullpointerexception on my facade and I discovered it happens whenever I use the Entity Manager.

My UDP server main class (this is the class I use to test but it happens the same with the class that is deployed).

```
public class UDPServerRun {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("UDP Server");
    try {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(8282);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[9];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[9];
        while (true) {
            RegistrarEntrada entrada = new RegistrarEntrada();

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence + "!");

            entrada.setCadenaEntrada(sentence);
            String cadena = entrada.registrar();

            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();
            sendData = cadena.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket
                    = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistrarEntrada.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the class that connects with the Facade (Also a test class).

```
public class RegistrarEntrada implements Serializable {

private AsistenciasFacadeLocal facade = new AsistenciasFacade();

private String cadenaEntrada;

public RegistrarEntrada() {

}

public String registrar() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int idPersonal = -1;

    String entradas[] = cadenaEntrada.split(" ");
    String idChecador = entradas[0];
    String idTarjeta = entradas[1];
    //String idChecador = "A1";
    //String idTarjeta = "F37C96";
    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    //try {
    idPersonal = facade.consultarIdPersonal(idTarjeta);
    //        } catch (Exception e) {
    //            System.out.println(e);
    //        }

    if (idPersonal != -1) {
        Personal persona = facade.consultarPersona(idPersonal);

        if (persona != null) {
            facade.registrarEntrada(idPersonal, idChecador);
            return persona.getNombre() + " se registro a las: " + timeFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        } else {
            return "Error 02";
        }
    } else {
        return "Error 01";
    }

}

//Getters and Setters
public String getCadenaEntrada() {
    return cadenaEntrada;
}

public void setCadenaEntrada(String cadenaEntrada) {
    this.cadenaEntrada = cadenaEntrada;
}

public AsistenciasFacadeLocal getFacade() {
    return facade;
}

public void setFacade(AsistenciasFacadeLocal facade) {
    this.facade = facade;
}

}
```

The Facade (I will mark the line where I get the error).

```
@Stateless
public class AsistenciasFacade implements AsistenciasFacadeLocal,     AsistenciasFacadeRemote {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "uvaqAsistenciasPU")
private EntityManager em;

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public AsistenciasFacade() {
    getEntityManager();
}

@Override
public void registrarEntrada(int idPersonal, String idChecador) {
    Registros registro = new Registros();
    Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();

    registro.setIdpersonal(idPersonal);
    registro.setFechahoraregistro(fecha.getTime());
    registro.setIdchecador(idChecador);
    em.persist(registro);
}

@Override
public Personal consultarPersona(int idPersonal) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE IDPERSONAL=" + idPersonal;
    List<Personal> objList = null;
    objList = em.createNativeQuery(query, Personal.class).getResultList();
    if (objList.size() != 0) {
        return objList.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int consultarIdPersonal(String idTarjeta) {
    int idPersonal;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM credenciales WHERE IDTARJETA = '" + idTarjeta + "'";
    List<Credenciales> objList = null;
    objList = em.createNativeQuery(query, Credenciales.class).getResultList();  //<====== The error happens here and also in every place where I use the entity manager
    if (objList.size() != 0) {
        idPersonal = Integer.parseInt(objList.get(0).getIdpersonal());
        return idPersonal;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}

@Override
public void sincronizarPersonal(List<String[]> personal) {
    System.out.println("Funcion Sincronizar Personal en Asistencias");
    List<Personal> nuevoPersonaltodos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < personal.size(); i++) {
        Personal nuevoPersonal = new Personal();
        nuevoPersonal.setIdpersonal(Integer.parseInt(personal.get(i)[0]));
        nuevoPersonal.setNombre(personal.get(i)[1]);
        nuevoPersonal.setApellidopat(personal.get(i)[2]);
        nuevoPersonal.setApellidomat(personal.get(i)[3]);
        nuevoPersonal.setIdstatusper(Integer.parseInt(personal.get(i)[4]));
        nuevoPersonaltodos.add(nuevoPersonal);
    }
    try {
        em.persist(nuevoPersonaltodos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
}
```

I'm trying to explain the problem, right now I don't have the server log but as soon as I can get it I will write it here.

Edit:
My log says this.

```
GRAVE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Post the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `RegistrarEntrada` you're instantiating the EJB, `AsistenciasFacade`. In order for the `EntityManager` to be injected the EJB needs to be managed by the container. This means that lifecycle for `RegistrarEntrada` would also need to be managed by the container and you'd have to inject the `AsistenciasFacade` EJB.

In other words you can't instantiate an object and have resources injected into it. The container needs to handle the complete lifecycle of these types of objects.

Comment: Well I'm not too sure what exactly you're doing so it's tough to say. But if you're doing `new AsistenciasFacade()` the `EntityManger` will always be `null` because you're managing the lifecycle not that container.

Comment: Ok so... I just want to know how a can use the EntityManager from RegistrarEntrada.

Comment: If you want to use it outside of the container, which kind of looks like what you're doing, you'd need to instantiate it.